# Eventstoredb: Cannot connect to cluster (3 nodes)

Tags: c#, eventstoredb

I am having trouble connecting to eventstore cluster (with 3 nodes). So I have a 3 nodes each running on Azure VM and below is the code to connect and append streams

```
var settings = EventStoreClientSettings.Create("esdb://admin:changeit@{node1IP}:2113,{node2IP}:2113,{node3IP}:2113?tls=true&tlsVerifyCert=false&keepAliveTimeout=10000&keepAliveInterval=10000");

var client = new EventStoreClient(settings);
                
var evt = new 
{
    EntityId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"),
    mportantData = "I wrote my first event!"
};
                
var eventData = new EventData(
    uid.NewUuid(),
    "TestEvent",
    JsonSerializer.SerializeToUtf8Bytes(evt)
);
                
await client.AppendToStreamAsync(
    "some-stream",
    StreamRevision.None, 
    new[] { eventData });
                
var result = client.ReadStreamAsync(
    Direction.Forwards,
    "some-stream",
    StreamPosition.Start);
                
var events = await result.ToListAsync();
foreach (var eventIn in events)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"event: {eventIn.ToString()}\n");
}
```

Error I am getting is
`DiscoveryException: Failed to discover candidate in 10 attempts.`

I can telnet the address from my local machine and seems to the problem is only with gRPC connection.

```
---
# Paths
Db: /var/lib/eventstore
Index: /var/lib/eventstore/index
Log: /var/log/eventstore
LogLevel: Information
# LogFileInterval: 62
LogFileRetentionCount: 100

SkipDbVerify: True
SkipIndexVerify: True
ChunksCacheSize: 1073741824
CachedChunks: 4

# Certificates configuration
CertificateFile: /etc/eventstore/certs/node.crt
CertificatePrivateKeyFile: /etc/eventstore/certs/node.key
TrustedRootCertificatesPath: /etc/eventstore/certs/ca

# Network configuration
## TCP/IP Settings
IntIp: 10.3.0.4
ExtIp: 10.3.0.4
IntTcpPort: 1112
ExtTcpPort: 1113
IntTcpHeartbeatInterval: 5000
IntTcpHeartbeatTimeout: 2000
ExtTcpHeartbeatInterval: 5000
ExtTcpHeartbeatTimeout: 2000

## HTTP Settings
HttpPort: 2113
HttpPortAdvertiseAs: 2113

# Cluster gossip
ClusterSize: 3
DiscoverViaDns: false
GossipSeed: 10.3.0.5:2113,10.3.0.6:2113

# Projections configuration
RunProjections: All
StartStandardProjections: True

# Misc Settings
EnableExternalTcp: True
EnableAtomPubOverHTTP: True
---
```

server config for one of the node, other 2 looks pretty much same except for the ip changes.

[image]

```
Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="DeadlineExceeded", Detail="")
   at EventStore.Client.Interceptors.TypedExceptionInterceptor.<AsyncUnaryCall>b__5_0[TRequest,TResponse](Task`1 t)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__272_0(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at EventStore.Client.GrpcServerCapabilitiesClient.GetAsync(CallInvoker callInvoker, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at EventStore.Client.EventStoreClientBase.GetChannelInfoExpensive(ReconnectionRequired reconnectionRequired, Action`1 onReconnectionRequired, IChannelSelector channelSelector, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at EventStore.Client.SharingProvider`2.FillBoxAsync(TaskCompletionSource`1 box, TInput input)
   at EventStore.Client.TaskExtensions.WithCancellation[T](Task`1 task, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at EventStore.Client.EventStoreClientBase.GetChannelInfo(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at EventStore.Client.EventStoreClient.<CreateStreamAppender>g__GetCall|14_0()
   at EventStore.Client.EventStoreClient.StreamAppender.IsUsable()
   at EventStore.Client.EventStoreClient.AppendToStreamAsync(String streamName, StreamRevision expectedRevision, IEnumerable`1 eventData, Action`1 configureOperationOptions, Nullable`1 deadline, UserCredentials userCredentials, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at TestClusterConnection.Program.Main() in /Users/krishna/Desktop/TestClusterConnection/TestClusterConnection/Program.cs:line 97
Unhandled exception. Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="DeadlineExceeded", Detail="")
   at EventStore.Client.Interceptors.TypedExceptionInterceptor.<AsyncUnaryCall>b__5_0[TRequest,TResponse](Task`1 t)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__272_0(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at EventStore.Client.GrpcServerCapabilitiesClient.GetAsync(CallInvoker callInvoker, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at EventStore.Client.EventStoreClientBase.GetChannelInfoExpensive(ReconnectionRequired reconnectionRequired, Action`1 onReconnectionRequired, IChannelSelector channelSelector, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at EventStore.Client.SharingProvider`2.FillBoxAsync(TaskCompletionSource`1 box, TInput input)
   at EventStore.Client.TaskExtensions.WithCancellation[T](Task`1 task, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at EventStore.Client.EventStoreClientBase.GetChannelInfo(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at EventStore.Client.EventStoreClient.<CreateStreamAppender>g__GetCall|14_0()
   at EventStore.Client.EventStoreClient.StreamAppender.IsUsable()
   at EventStore.Client.EventStoreClient.AppendToStreamAsync(String streamName, StreamRevision expectedRevision, IEnumerable`1 eventData, Action`1 configureOperationOptions, Nullable`1 deadline, UserCredentials userCredentials, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at TestClusterConnection.Program.Main() in /Users/krishna/Desktop/TestClusterConnection/TestClusterConnection/Program.cs:line 97
   at TestClusterConnection.Program.<Main>()
```

Error logs I can see in the console...

Comment: You are connecting to a secure cluster, what's your server config (one node is enough) and certificate CN and SANs?

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev added the config.

Comment: Where does you run your code from ?

Is it from a machine in the same ip range ? (I.e same or other network)

can you perform a curl from that machine where that program is run from & give the output ?

curl -i -k -u admin:changeit https://10.3.0.4:2113/web/index.html
curl -i -k -u admin:changeit https://10.3.0.5:2113/web/index.html
    curl -i -k -u admin:changeit https://10.3.0.6:2113/web/index.html

Comment: @ylorph Tried to run from local machine and the error is same as above and also tried to run from a VM in the same azure network and still the same error. Tried the curl you provided and the result is `curl: (28) Failed to connect to 10.3.0.4 port 2113 after 75007 ms: Operation timed out` (because the IP is azure private ip). Tried the curl with external ip as well and the result is `curl: (52) Empty reply from server`

Comment: * "Local Machine" what do you mean  ?

* "WM in same azure network" : that's odd.  

* Are the nodes able to see each others ?  any errors in the logs `/var/log/eventstore` ?

Comment: @ylorph Local machine means my personal computer, eventstore is running on the azure vms. Nodes able to gossip each other. See the newly attached picutre above.

Comment: I am confused as the logs show that you connect via TCP, but the code you show uses the gRPC client. Even the logger context name is `EventStoreConnection` which corresponds with the TCP client. Could you please clarify that?

Comment: Just to make 100% sure: the following line:
`var settings = EventStoreClientSettings.Create("esdb://admin:changeit@{node1IP}:2113,{node2IP}:2113,{node3IP}:2113?tls=true&tlsVerifyCert=false&keepAliveTimeout=10000&keepAliveInterval=10000");`

you did repleace {node1IP}, {node2IP}, {node3IP} with the corresponding IP addresses ?

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev sorry for the confusion, its my bad to put the wrong console logs, was trying different kinds of connections and none of them are working. Updated the logs now.

Comment: @ylorph Updated the logs now

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev FYI I have added the server cert (ca.crt) to the keychain and set that to `Trust Always`. I have a string feeling that it must be wrong with either client or with the network.

Comment: It seems it's your local machine that can't connect to the vnet in azure.
Where did you take the screenshot from  ?